# How to suppress the 'stop running this script' prompt in the c# WebBrowser control?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I have a WebBrowser control inside a C# dialog that calls a C# function from JavaScript (via an HTML button). This sets off a fairly lengthy operation in C# code. Ideally, I would like the user to be able to leave it to continue unattended. Unfortunately since it's kicked off from JavaScript it's periodically interrupted by the following prompt, requiring the user to make a yes/no selection before it will continue:

> Stop running this script?
>
> A script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly. If it
>   continues to run, your computer might become unresponsive.

Is there any way to suppress this message in the control so that it can continue uninterrupted? I've tried setting ScriptErrorsSuppressed to true but it doesn't seem to work for this particular message.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm sure someone would be able to help if you added your code (in particular, what you think it's causing the issue). It seems like something that should be handled through AJAX, but not seeing the code it's hard to tell

Comment: Does any potential solution have to block further actions within the embedded browser, or would it be ok for someone to continue to interact with the page while the operation runs in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing that message because Javascript is waiting for the function to return, and execution is sitting in the C# side during your lengthy operation.

When the user hits the button, have C# kick off the operation using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` [(msdn)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx) or a `BackgroundWorker` [(msdn)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx).  While the operation is running, execution can return to the Javascript.  Then have the C# tell the Javascript when the job is done.